# Não consigo visualizar a pagina form.jsf

Tags: spring-mvc

Não consigo visualizar a pagina form.jsp

estou colocando a seguinte URL   http://localhost:8080/Loja/

Com essa URL ele somente visualiza a pagina hello-world.jsp

eu até coloco o seguinte endereço  http://localhost:8080/Loja/produtos/form mas gera erro, aonde será que estou errando.

aqui está o meu projeto completo;

Isso aconteceu depois que configurei o projeto para conexão com o banco de dados

https://github.com/wladimirbandeira/Loja/tree/master/Loja

Comment: no enunciado vc diz que é form.jsf, o que é estranho. mas no github é um arquivo jps!
além disso seu diretório tá errado, "produto"  é "products" e o form tem que ter a extensão do arquivo, no caso ".jsp".

Comment: aonde está como .jps  ?