# Problemas na configuração do projeto Spring

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc

Crie um `controller` chamado **HomeController** e coloque as seguintes configurações:

- [Primeira Configuração](https://github.com/wladimirbandeira/Loja/blob/master/Loja/src/main/java/br/com/casadocodigo/loja/controller/HomeController.java)

Beleza até ai tudo bem. Depois disso tem que configurar o projeto para ele enxergar a página que está nesse pacote:

- [Segunda Configuração](https://github.com/wladimirbandeira/Loja/blob/master/Loja/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/hello-world.jsp)

Para isso tem que criar duas *classes*, respectivamente:

- [Primeira Classe](https://github.com/wladimirbandeira/Loja/blob/master/Loja/src/main/java/br/com/casadocodigo/loja/conf/ServletSpringMVC.java)
- [Segunda Classe](https://github.com/wladimirbandeira/Loja/blob/master/Loja/src/main/java/br/com/casadocodigo/loja/conf/AppWebConfiguration.java)

Essa configuração é comum de existir em arquivos *XML*, mas ela está sendo feita em *classe Java*, tudo bem, é uma tendência de substituir *XML* por uma *classe Java*. Até aqui está tudo bem.

Quando coloco para compilar tenho sucesso em receber essa mensagem para a *classe* **HomeController**:

> olâ.

E fiz o mesmo com a *classe* **ProductsController**:

- [Classe ProductsConstroller](https://github.com/wladimirbandeira/Loja/blob/master/Loja/src/main/java/br/com/casadocodigo/loja/controller/ProductsController.java)

Sendo que, fiz as seguintes modificações:

```
@Controller
public class ProductsController {

    @RequestMapping("/produtos/")
    public String save(){
        System.out.println("carregando produto");
        return "products/ok";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/produtos/form")
    public String form(){
        return "/products/form";
    }
```

Ao iniciar o **TomCat** era para colocar as seguintes *URL´s:*

> localhost:8080/Loja/products/ok

Com essa *URL* acima, era para aparecer a mensagem de erro `404`, porém apareceria no *console* do *eclipse* a mensagem *"carregando produto"*, mas não foi isso que aconteceu, apareceu a mensagem de erro na pagina mas não apareceu a mensagem no *console* do *eclipse*.

Depois testei essa *URL*;

> http://localhost:8080/Loja/products/form

E era para aparece a página `JSP`, mas não aparece nada, somente a mensagem de erro `404`.

**Onde será que errei ?**

Comment: Essa questão é a mesma que [esta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92266/n%C3%A3o-consigo-visualizar-a-pagina-form-jsf)?

Comment: não, só tem uma diferença, eu tinha começado tudo de novo e não coloquei configuração de conexão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está usando **products/ok** no retorno de *save* e você não tem uma pagina **ok.jsp**, crie uma ou mude o retorno.

Já no método *form* você está retornando **/products/form**, tire a primeira '**/**' e vai bombar, ficando assim:

```
@RequestMapping("/produtos/form")
public String form(){
    return "products/form";
}
```